# Google script to copy a newly added row from one sheet and append to another only if it doesn't exist in the second sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, append

I have a google sheet (Sheet 1) which gets auto-populated by a script. Now I want to copy the newly added rows to Sheet 2 only if doesn't exist in Sheet 2. I am trying to match column 1 from both the sheets and if it doesnt exist in sheet 2, the row should be appended in sheet 2. I do not have much experience in google script. Here is my code.

```
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Original');
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Filtered');
  var values1 = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var values2 = s2.getDataRange().getValues();
  var resultArray = [];
  for(var n=0; n < values1.length ; n++)
  {
    var keep = false;
    var counter = 0;
    for(var p=0; p < values2.length ; p++)
    {
      if( values1[n][1] == values2[p][1])
      {
        keep = true;
        break ;
      }
    }
    if(keep == false)
    {
      resultArray.push(values1[n]);      
      s2.appendRow();
      resultArray = [];
      keep = false
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks good. Isn't it working?

Comment: No. I am not sure if I have used the appendRow() function correctly. Not very familiar with objects too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an argument to appendRow function. You currently append nothing. See here for an example.

```
var aRow = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow( aRow );
```

On your end, you should have a array which is populated with the values you want to copy for a particular row. If that row does not exist in sheet2, then add it there.

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)

Comment: It worked. Just didn't know how to use it :) Thank you for your help.